# Environs package will not work on python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, pypi

I have a problem with running a python script with environs package using the command python3

For example the script is called envir.py and I call it with:

```
python3 envir.py
```

And this will yield the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "envir.py", line 2, in <module>
from environs import Env
File "/home/zarko/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/environs.py", 
line 24, in <module>
Subcast = typing.Union[typing.Type, typing.Callable[..., T]]
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 552, in __getitem__
dict(self.__dict__), parameters, _root=True)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in __new__
for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in <genexpr>
for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 1077, in 
__subclasscheck__
if super().__subclasscheck__(cls):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/abc.py", line 225, in __subclasscheck__
for scls in cls.__subclasses__():
TypeError: descriptor '__subclasses__' of 'type' object needs an argument
```

If I use the "python" command to run the script it works with no problems

Here is what the script looks like

```
from environs import Env
env = Env()
env.read_env()
ACCESS_KEY = env("ACCESS_KEY")
```

Comment: not reproducable, working fine with python 2 and 3

Comment: What `environs` version are you using? Can you import `environs` and then check the value of `environs.__version__`?

Comment: @00 the version number is 4.2.0

Comment: @00 I don't understand why it isn't the latest version. I use the command "pip install environs"

Comment: Are the outputs when you run `which python` and `which python3` the same? If not, you have multiple versions of python installed on your system. `pip install environs` will only install for the version pointed by `python`. You might want to `python3 -m pip install environs`.

Comment: @djoffe
Thank you very much. I spend a lot of time until I found your answer.
You could write your comment as answer so I could mark it as 'useful!